# Javascript uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I am trying to implement the JS code given here:

```
https://davidlozzi.com/2011/08/09/sharepoint-defaulting-external-links-to-open-in-a-new-window/
```

So that all external links open in a new window. I copied the `JS` into notepad and saved it in a new folder, `StyleLibrary/scripts`. However, I keep getting errors on the code when I look at dev tools:
[image]

I tried the original version with script tags, but it gave me uncaught syntax error on "<"... I also changed the `$` to `jQuery` just to see if it would work.

The script link I added looks like the following:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" Defer = "true" runat="server" Localizable="true" name="~sitecollection/Style Library/scripts/externalLinkNewWindow.js" />-->
```

Any Ideas as to why I keep getting these errors? The code isn't running because of them.

Comment: Start with the easy stuff:

1) Is Jquery Loaded, you didn't post a script tag so I wouldn't know, also make sure it isn't loaded in 2 script tags as all sorts of havoc can ensue then

2) The preferred style for calling Jquery now is "$" or $(document).ready(function(){//code goes here});

Comment: Jquery must be loaded, i use it on other pages... I changed it back to $

Comment: sounds like a loading order then, this might be trying to run prior to jQuery being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that jQuery linking lines should come first before that your external js files, For example

```
 <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Test.js"></script>
    </head>
```